# How can i just have one Component instead of different components in the context of Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, components

I am new to Vuejs, I am using 4 different components, where in every component i have called the API. Here 4 different components are all same except their contents.

Now, i want to make my code effective, so i want to have a single component, the reason why i created different components is my another App.vue component has 4 different buttons, so whenever you click any of it, it will open the respective component.

But now i want to have only one component instead of four different components, and whenever the buttons in App.vue component is clicked it should open the exact content in single component(instead of 4 components).

Please do help me with this, by sharing your ideas and if any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, you can use **props**, which is a way of passing data to "child" components.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

#### Example

*App.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <SingleComponent :button="button" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SingleComponent from "@/components/SingleComponent.vue";
// @/ means src/

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SingleComponent,
  },
  data: () => ({
    button: 2,
  }),
};
</script>
```

*SingleComponent.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-if="button === 0">...</button>
    <button v-else-if="button === 1">...</button>
    <button v-else-if="button === 2">...</button>
    <button v-else-if="button === 3">...</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SingleComponent",
  props: {
    button: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

You should also take a look at **slots**, it is very important in Vue.js and that could also solve your problem.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html